# Mysql just appear line where count 3 lines in result

Tags: mysql, count

I'm trying to get a result: just appear line where the id is 6 and the number of lines is 3

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS number FROM tableexample WHERE id = 6 AND number = '3'
```

but i have a error unknow colunn number

some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a column alias in where clause. Use having instead:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS number FROM tableexample WHERE id = 6 having number = '3'
```